# prevFrame(); didn't work

Tags: flash

i've made a movie clip with nextFrame and PrevFrame action..my problem is the prevFrame action  didn't work(not even triggered as buttton) on my last frame..anyone can help?here's my code

```
stop();

import  flash.display.MovieClip;
import  flash.events.MouseEvent;

close_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onPressClose);
next_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onPressNext);
prev_btn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onPressPrev);

close_btn.buttonMode = true;
close_btn.useHandCursor = true;
next_btn.buttonMode = true;
next_btn.useHandCursor = true;
prev_btn.buttonMode = true;
prev_btn.useHandCursor = true;

function onPressClose( event:MouseEvent):void{
 this.gotoAndStop(1);
 }

 function onPressNext( event:MouseEvent):void{
 this.nextFrame();
 }

 function onPressPrev( event:MouseEvent):void{
 this.prevFrame();
 }
```

here's is my file
http://speedy.sh/xUgeq/next-and-prev.zip

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused what you're trying to do here... Are the two buttons (next_button and prev_button) on the main Timeline or are they nested within a Movie Clip? If they are nested within a Movie Clip then this code will work:

```
mc.next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPressNext);
function onPressNext(e:MouseEvent){
    mc.nextFrame();
}

mc.prev_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPressPrev);
function onPressPrev(e:MouseEvent){
    mc.prevFrame();
}
```

Otherwise if the buttons are on the main Timeline then this code will work for your buttons:

```
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPressNext);
function onPressNext(e:MouseEvent){
    nextFrame();
}

prev_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onPressPrev);
function onPressPrev(e:MouseEvent){
    prevFrame();
}
```

By the way, I didn't take a look at your file because I have a bad history with sites like "speedy share", they always seem to mess up my computer. :P

Cheers,
Drake Swartzy

Comment: prev_btn on the last frame is not functioning

Comment: btw, they're nested within a movie clip

Comment: I'm not quite sure why that is... Try looking through your buttons and checking to make sure that their instance names agree with your code... Usually problems like these result from some small mistake. Are you receiving any compiler errors?